# Marketplace registration incomplete - Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, certificate, verification, marketplace

One of my friend registered for the Windows Phone 7 developer account, He thought that he has finished it but when I connect my WP7 device in and login using that developer account. I received this error message: " Marketplace registration incomplete, the errorcode is 0x80043009 "

Does anyone know what happens, does he lack some information or I just need to wait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error code indicates Geotrust identity verification has not been completed.

Your friend should follow this up with Geotrust and can check progress on AppHub under My Dashboard -> Windows Phone.

Comment: he also registered with GeoTrust and receive the approval email

Comment: Besides getting the email, you need to go through their identity verification process. You can verify this is not complete by going to the link I described and seeing the tick is missing.